# Why are margin-values of butterworth bandpass filter so unrealistically big?

Tags: python, filter, bandpass-filter, butterworth

I use a butterworth bandpass:

```
def butter_bandpass_prep(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    """Butterworth bandpass auxilliary function."""
     nyq = 0.5 * fs # Minimal frequency (nyquist criterion)
     low = lowcut / nyq
     high = highcut / nyq
     b, a = sp.signal.butter(order, [low, high], btype='band')
     return b, a

def butter_bandpass(src, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    """Butterworth bandpass filter."""
    b, a = butter_bandpass_prep(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
    dst = sp.signal.filtfilt(b, a, src)
    return dst
```

I general it seems to work well, but at the margins I always get some unrealistic values. It seems as if the filtered margin-values drop to zero...
Is there a way to prevent that from happening?
Thank you a lot!

[image: green: unfiltered, blue: filtered]
[image: green: unfiltered, blue: filtered]

Comment: If you don't get any luck here, might be worth asking on https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thank you. I did so and was linked to [https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16869/removing-transients-in-highpass-filtering-with-matlab] which actually helped!